# Python in power BI to get data does not give data

Tags: python, powerbi

I have a Python script to get data from a website. This works perfect in Visual Studio Code. Now I run the same in Power BI. It does not give me an error bust I do not get data at all.

This is my piece of code to create the dataset:

```
    table = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ContentTable')
    rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')

    row_num = 0
    l = []
    for row in rows:
        if row_num > 0:
            td = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
            row2 = [row.text for row in td]
            l.append(row2)
        row_num = row_num + 1
    df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],dtype=object)  
    raise Exception(df)
    #print(df)
```

In Visual studio, I get 21 rows in "df"
PowerBI does not create the dataset.

What can be the difference?

Comment: Couldn't you do some `try` /  `except` and check for error messages? Like in `row.find_elements` maybe I think

Comment: Check what is the content of 'rows'. Also check if You actually receive page content.

Comment: It would be easier if you give all code required to run this function.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My script used functions, I had to pass df to my initial function and call this one like this:

```
output = main()
```